# multibit balances wrong, not correct for any individual address

Tags: wallet, blockchain, address, multibit, balance

In my multibit wallet, it reports X bitcoins.  But no address in that wallet contains exactly X bitcoin, and the total reported amount should be greater than X.

The reason this is stranger than normal is because when additional bitcoin is sent to an address in that wallet, the X increases by the right amount, but it just conveniently forgets to accurately display an amount that is reflected in ANY single address in that wallet

Address 1 has W bitcoin in it, W is less than the reported X amount
Address 2 has Y bitcoin in it, Y is greater than the reported X amount
Address 3 has 0 bitcoin in it.

So X is some combination of Address 1 and Address 2's balance, but it is not either of them

The "3 reset" trick does NOTHING to fix this. And in some gamble that it does display my whole balance after a blockchain reset, it only displays it until a transaction is made, or the application is restarted. In which case my only resource seems to be to reset the blockchain over and over again, or consider MultiBit's HORRIBLE non-advise of moving everything to a new wallet in a different application by exposing the private keys.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

due to this bug and other reported bugs seemingly related to improper accounting of change addresses escalating to **LOST BITCOINS** see someone else's post here: (http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/22gt4r/major_mulitibit_bug_btc_gone_it_cost_me_all_of_my/)

I've switched to electrum, fortunately at the time (tons of blockchain resets), multibit was reporting my entire balance and was able to move it all to my electrum addresses.